# Glass GDK Authentication: upload app to glassware needed

Tags: authentication, google-glass

I'm developing a Glass app using GDK and Mirror API. I'm stuck with the GDK Authentication feature launched in XE16. I'm getting a response '404 Not Found' when trying to insert the account with the Mirror API:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/accounts/{userToken}/com.example.myapp/username%40email.com

I'm not sure if I have to upload my app first to glassware to be able to test it. The authentication doc kind of said that:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication

It is possible to upload my app to test this functionality without making it public to others?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the authentication system documented at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication correct? Note the box at the top of that page that reads

`Note: Currently, you can only test and use this API after we've uploaded your APK to MyGlass, which happens during the review process.`

This is required to get the {userToken} portion of the URL that you need to use to transmit the information.

Best practice is to hardcode the information you need during your preliminary testing while you're sideloading the app. When you're ready, review the submission guidelines and checklist at https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/index and submit it for review. As part of the review process, you will make the apk available to the Glass team and you can request a whitelist of addresses who will be able to test loading the app via MyGlass before it is public.